# Move a file based on its filename

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I have a networked PDF printer. It has an auto-save abilities but doesn't allow me to save in user-specified folders (e.g., `\\server\users\<username>\pdfs\`).

It does allow for a program to be ran after the save. So, what I need is a script to run after the save and move the file based on the filename to that particular user's save directory.

Currently, the auto-saves are generating with `username<date/time>.pdf`, so I need a script that:

1. Scans the folder where they will be auto-saved
2. Pulls the username from the filename and moves the file to `\\servername\users\<username>\pdfs\`

My Googlefu is not working out too well and my scripting abilities are very limited. Any help is appreciated.

This is currently what I am working with:

```psh
$autoSaveDir = "c:\autosave"
$userDir = "c:\userdir\%username%\pdfs"
$regexFirstNumber = "^[^\d]*(\d+)"

#iterate through the auto save directory
Get-ChildItem -Path $autoSaveDir -File | ForEach-Object {
  #find the username portion of the file by splitting on the first number in the filename
  $dateInFileName = [regex]::split($_.Name,'^[^\d]*(\d+)')

  $fileNameParts = $_.Name -split $dateInFileName[1]
  $userName = $fileNameParts[0]

  $newFile = $userDir -replace "%username%", $username
  $newFile = $newFile + "\" + $_.Name

  #copy the file over - doesn't check to make sure the folders are there first though
  Copy-Item $_.FullName $newFile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This VBScript should do what you need:

```vb
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each File In .GetFolder("c:\autosave").Files
        If StrComp(.GetExtensionName(File.Name), "pdf", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

            strUser     = .GetBaseName(File.Path)
            strUserRoot = .BuildPath("c:\userdir", strUser)
            strUserPdf  = .BuildPath(strUserRoot, "pdfs")

            If Not .FolderExists(strUserRoot) Then .CreateFolder strUserRoot
            If Not .FolderExists(strUserPdf)  Then .CreateFolder strUserPdf

            File.Move strUserPdf & "\"

        End If
    Next
End With
```

---

**Edit:**

If the files are named in `yyyymmddhhnnssUsername.pdf` format, just strip off the first 14 characters to determine the username:

```vb
strUser = Mid(.GetBaseName(File.Path), 15)
```

When the file is moved, it will still contain the timestamp.

Comment: I modified it a little bit, but am getting "line 4 char 13 Path not Found"

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each File In .GetFolder("c:\pdfcreator").Files
        If StrComp(.GetExtensionName(File.Name), "pdf", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            File.Move "c:\networkstorage\userstorage\" & .GetBaseName(File.Path) & "\pdfs\"
        End If
    Next
End With

Comment: Do the destination folders for each user need to be created or do they already exist?

Comment: The test user the folder already exists    here is an example of the output file before the script is ran     20150720104631administrator.pdf

c:\networkstorage\userstorage\administrator\pdfs exists

Comment: So the files have a timestamp on them? Your question says they're named `username.pdf`.

Comment: I removed the timestamp, and ran the vbs and still get the error regardless, but I can remove the timestamp if that makes coding easier.

so now administrator.pdf located in c:\pdfcreator still doesn't move to c:\networkstorage\userstorage\administrator\pdfs

Comment: I've edited it to create the folder if it doesn't exist. You'll want to make sure the user account under which the script is being run has permission to your path.

Comment: Ok so now it works for the first time, but when you run it again, you get an error message because it cannot move the file to that same directory because they have the same filename, is there a way to append the date and time to the filename before or after it's moved? Or changing the filename in some way?  

By the way thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You could add the timestamp back to the original filename and we could work around it. How would it look with the time in the filename? `yyyymmddhhnnssuser.pdf`?

Comment: 20150720122329username.pdf

or 

username20150720122329.pdf

whatever is easiest

this is correct ! yyyymmddhhnnssuser.pdf

Comment: BOOM goes the dynomite, works perfectly thank you so much Bond it won't let me upvote you because im brand new here, any other way I can give you credit on this thread?

Comment: You can accept it as an answer for your question, if you want. But no worries. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my Answer thanks Bond!

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each File In .GetFolder("c:\pdfcreator").Files
    If StrComp(.GetExtensionName(File.Name), "pdf", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

        strUser = Mid(.GetBaseName(File.Path), 15)
        strUserRoot = .BuildPath("C:\Network Storage\Userstorage", strUser)
        strUserPdf  = .BuildPath(strUserRoot, "pdfs")

        If Not .FolderExists(strUserRoot) Then .CreateFolder strUserRoot
        If Not .FolderExists(strUserPdf)  Then .CreateFolder strUserPdf

        File.Move strUserPdf & "\"

    End If
Next
End With
```